# Magento2: Add product via external form

Tags: magento2, api, product-attribute, json

I'm making a database connection between two seperate systems. I found a lot of options for updating existing products, but is there also a way to add new products through the Magento2 API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Is there also a way to add new products through the Magento2 API?
```

You can update or add product by using  Rest `/rest/V1/products` or Soap.

```
<?
//Authentication rest API magento2.Please change url accordingly your url
    $adminUrl='http://localhost/magento/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token';
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array("username" => "", "password" => "");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                       
$ch = curl_init($adminUrl); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);       
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$token=  json_decode($token);

//Use above token into header
$headers = array('Authorization=> Bearer $token'); 

$requestUrl='http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/rest/V1/products';
//Please note 24-MB01 is sku

$ch = curl_init();
$ch = curl_init($requestUrl); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$post ='{
  "product": {
        "sku": "B201-SKU",
        "name": "B202",
        "price": 30.00,
        "status": 1,
        "type_id": "simple",
        "attribute_set_id":4,
        "weight": 1
    },
  "saveOptions": true
}';

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL=>$toURL,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($post)),
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>0,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)",
    CURLOPT_POST=>true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>$post,

);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result=  json_decode($result);
print_r($result);


?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: At first it didn't work because of the HTTP header, but after replacing the "=>" with ":" (because it's in a string) it works properly without giving error. Thanks